# How to get the total number of months for selected period in Google Analytics? Can we dynamically display the current months for a custom repoort?

Tags: google-analytics, formula, average

I am trying to get the average number of users or sessions per month for GA custom reports.  In Google Analytics, i can get total num of users or sessions, however there is no way to get total number of months in time dimension to calculate average users per month, and I was not able to find time dimension data show up in calculated formula any way. Any suggestions?  Thanks, Hong

Comment: It would be desirable that you include the code you have already tried in your question. As the question stands anyone wanting to help you is left to code the entirety. Please consider the guidelines on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use '**Month of the year**' dimension:

[image]

Or if you want you can use '**Month of year**' dimension to get the months in **YYYYMM** format.